# Access asp:HiddenField through javascript from target page in anchor tag

Tags: javascript, forms, anchor, element, href

I have a page (startPage.aspx) which transfers control to another page using an anchor tag i.e. (a href="newPage.aspx"). I would like to know how I can access some form element on startPage.aspx from the newPage.aspx in javascript? (eg: document.getElementById, etc). The element I am trying to access is an asp:HiddenField which does not have a name attribute.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: You're following the anchor to go to the new page?  Also what type or how much data is in this field?

Comment: Yes, I'm clicking the anchor to go to the destination "newPage.aspx". The field is a 144 byte string.